# Como comparar y fusionar dos arrays cuando hay alguna coincidencia?

Tags: php, array, foreach

Muy buenas, estoy intentando hacer un algoritmo pero tengo una falla. Tengos dos arrays:
Array 1:

```
    array(9) {
  [3025]=>
  string(17) "Opción Ciudadana"
  [3019]=>
  string(30) "Partido Conservador Colombiano"
  [3020]=>
  string(14) "Cambio Radical"
  [3009]=>
  string(15) "Partido de la U"
  [3024]=>
  string(29) "Polo Democrático Alternativo"
  [3023]=>
  string(13) "Alianza Verde"
  [3012]=>
  string(19) "Centro Democrático"
  [3016]=>
  string(26) "Partido Liberal Colombiano"
  [3060]=>
  string(21) "Colombia Justa Libres"
}
```

Donde las keys son el codigo de cada partido
Array 2:

```
array(32) {
  ["Franklin del Cristo Lozano de la Ossa"]=>
  string(4) "3025"
  ["Félix Alejandro Chica"]=>
  string(4) "3019"
  ["Karen Violette Cure Corcione"]=>
  string(4) "3020"
  ["Nicolás Albeiro Echeverry"]=>
  string(4) "3019"
  ["Jose David Name Cardozo"]=>
  string(4) "3009"
  ["Jorge Enrique Robledo Castillo"]=>
  string(4) "3024"
  ["César Augusto Ortiz Zorro"]=>
  string(4) "3023"
  ["Ricardo Alfonso Ferro Lozano"]=>
  string(4) "3012"
  ["Edwin Gilberto Ballesteros Archila"]=>
  string(4) "3012"
  ["Rubén Darío Molano Piñeros "]=>
  string(4) "3012"
  ["Héctor Ángel Ortiz Núñez"]=>
  string(4) "3012"
  ["Óscar Camilo Arango Cárdenas"]=>
  string(4) "3020"
  ["Ciro Fernández Núñez"]=>
  string(4) "3020"
  ["Jorge Enrique Burgos Lugo"]=>
  string(4) "3009"
  ["Ángel María Gaitán Pulido"]=>
  string(4) "3016"
  ["Guillermo García Realpe"]=>
  string(4) "3016"
  ["Franklin del Cristo"]=>
  string(4) "3025"
  ["Luciano Grisales Londoño"]=>
  string(4) "3016"
  ["Sandra Liliana Ortíz Nova"]=>
  string(4) "3023"
  ["Jorge Eduardo Londoño Ulloa"]=>
  string(4) "3023"
  ["Flora Perdomo Andrade"]=>
  string(4) "3016"
  ["Didier Lobo Chinchilla"]=>
  string(4) "3020"
  ["Daira de Jesus Galvis Méndez"]=>
  string(4) "3020"
  ["Alonso José del Río Cabarcas"]=>
  string(4) "3009"
  ["Carlos Felipe Mejía Mejía"]=>
  string(4) "3012"
  ["Crisanto Pizo Mazabuel"]=>
  string(4) "3016"
  ["Juan Fernando Espinal Ramírez"]=>
  string(4) "3012"
  ["Nora María García Burgos"]=>
  string(4) "3019"
  ["Miguel Ángel Barreto Castillo"]=>
  string(4) "3019"
  ["Eduardo Emilio Pacheco Cuello"]=>
  string(4) "3060"
  ["José David Name Cardozo"]=>
  string(4) "3009"
  ["Maritza Martínez Aristizábal"]=>
  string(4) "3009"
}
```

Donde los values son los codigos de los partidos politicos del array 1 y las keys son el nombre de un congresista perteneciente a ese partido

Debo comparar ambos arrays y cuando el value del array 2 sea igual a la key del array 1 este value del array 2 debe entrar a llenarse a la key del array 1

Ejemplo de como debe quedar:

```
array(2){
   [3019]=>{
     [0] =>
        'Nicolás Albeiro Echeverry'
     [1]=>
        'Miguel Ángel Barreto Castillo'
   }
   [3020]{
     [0]=>
        'Óscar Camilo Arango Cárdenas'
     [1]=>
        'Ciro Fernández Núñez'
    
   }

}
```

Hasta el momento he intentado con varias funciones como array_merge o array_merge_recursive pero ninguna ha resultado, no se si alguien puede ayudar. Muchas gracias.

Comment: No creo que haya ninguna función especifica para hacer eso que buscas. Tendrás que primer recorrer un array, Quizás lo mejor sería clonar el primer array, y recorrerlo con array_map. Dentro de la función de array map ahí recorrés el segundo y la comparás con la key, y devolves todos los que tengan match.

Answer (score 0):

En este caso no se podría utilizar alguna de las funciones que estas utilizando, porque ya es un poco mas especifica la funcionalidad que necesitas.

```
$partidos = [
  "3025" => "Opción Ciudadana",
  "3019" => "Partido Conservador Colombiano",
  "3020" => "Cambio Radical",
  "3009" => "Partido de la U",
  "3024" => "Polo Democrático Alternativo",
  "3023" => "Alianza Verde",
  "3012" => "Centro Democrático",
  "3016" => "Partido Liberal Colombiano",
  "3060" => "Colombia Justa Libres",
];

$congresistas = [
  "Franklin del Cristo Lozano de la Ossa" => "3025",
  "Félix Alejandro Chica" => "3019",
  "Karen Violette Cure Corcione" => "3020",
  "Nicolás Albeiro Echeverry" => "3019",
  "Jose David Name Cardozo" => "3009",
  "Jorge Enrique Robledo Castillo" => "3024",
  "César Augusto Ortiz Zorro" => "3023",
  "Ricardo Alfonso Ferro Lozano" => "3012",
  "Edwin Gilberto Ballesteros Archila" => "3012",
  "Rubén Darío Molano Piñeros " => "3012",
  "Héctor Ángel Ortiz Núñez" => "3012",
  "Óscar Camilo Arango Cárdenas" => "3020",
  "Ciro Fernández Núñez" => "3020",
  "Jorge Enrique Burgos Lugo" => "3009",
  "Ángel María Gaitán Pulido" => "3016",
  "Guillermo García Realpe" => "3016",
  "Franklin del Cristo" => "3025",
  "Luciano Grisales Londoño" => "3016",
  "Sandra Liliana Ortíz Nova" => "3023",
  "Jorge Eduardo Londoño Ulloa" => "3023",
  "Flora Perdomo Andrade" => "3016",
  "Didier Lobo Chinchilla" => "3020",
  "Daira de Jesus Galvis Méndez" => "3020",
  "Alonso José del Río Cabarcas" => "3009",
  "Carlos Felipe Mejía Mejía" => "3012",
  "Crisanto Pizo Mazabuel" => "3016",
  "Juan Fernando Espinal Ramírez" => "3012",
  "Nora María García Burgos" => "3019",
  "Miguel Ángel Barreto Castillo" => "3019",
  "Eduardo Emilio Pacheco Cuello" => "3060",
  "José David Name Cardozo" => "3009",
  "Maritza Martínez Aristizábal" => "3009",
];

//Creamos un nuevo arreglo para que se arme la estructura que necesitamos
$nuevo = [];

//Recorremos el arreglo de $parditos
//Por cada partido recorremos el arreglo $congresistas
//Cuando el key sea igual que el value de los dos arreglos
//Agregamos el item al arreglo $nuevo
foreach ($partidos as $Pkey => $Pvalue) {
    foreach ($congresistas as $Ckey => $Cvalue) {
        if($Pkey == $Cvalue){
            $nuevo[$Pkey][] = $Ckey; 
        }
    }
}

var_dump($nuevo);
```

Comment: Oh muchas gracias amigo, no había pensado en esa solución

Comment: Si te funciono?

Comment: Si amigo, si funcionó